# File not Found when loading multipack spritesheet in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, texturepacker

I'm attempting to use multipacking via TexturePacker to handle multiple animations for the same sprite.  I added all my images in TexturePacker and published them, no problem.  I've added them to the Resources folder in my project and I even see them in Finder.

[image: Resources folder]

When I attempt to call this

```
-(CCSpriteBatchNode*)createSpritesheet {
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Clea1.plist"];

    CCSpriteBatchNode *spritesheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Clea1.png"];

    return spritesheet;
}
```

I wind up with the following errors:

```
2013-08-21 00:08:13.024 HFZ[10498:a0b] -[CCFileUtils fullPathForFilename:resolutionType:] : cocos2d: Warning: File not found: Clea1.plist
2013-08-21 00:08:13.025 HFZ[10498:a0b] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file 'Clea1.png' as texture
2013-08-21 00:08:13.025 HFZ[10498:a0b] -[CCFileUtils fullPathForFilename:resolutionType:] : cocos2d: Warning: File not found: Clea1.png
2013-08-21 00:08:13.026 HFZ[10498:a0b] cocos2d: Couldn't find file:Clea1.png
2013-08-21 00:08:13.026 HFZ[10498:a0b] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Frame 'CleaStand00.png' not found
```

I really don't understand why this is happening.  Before I tried the multipack solution, I was attempting to use one spritesheet per animation, but this seemed like the better route to go.  Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just guessing, but sometimes it happens to me that even when I add resources to the project, they don't appear in the `Copy Bundle Resources` `Build Phase`. Double-check that `Clea1.plist` and `Clea1.png` are on your `Copy Bundle Resources` section, otherwise drag them from the `Project navigator`

[image]